# Proof that entanglement "speed" cannot exceed the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, quantum-entanglement, causality

Is there a mathematical proof, if any, in the quantum mechanics formalism, proving that "entanglement" cannot be used to send information with speed greater than light?

**Remark (related):** can the speed of entanglement be defined and can it be demonstrated that it cannot exceed the speed of light?

Comment: Some numbers are even and some numbers are odd.  There is no such thing as the speed of evenness.  Some quantum states are entangled and some are not.  Why would you expect there to be such a thing as a speed of entanglement?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's the [No communication theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem), the basic fact that local operations don't affect a distant system. Let $\sigma=\sum_i T_i^A\otimes S_i^B$ be a (possibly entangled) state shared between Alice and Bob. Suppose Alice does a quantum operation $\mathcal{E}$ on her system with the intent of sending information to Bob (for example, a measurement, or any other operation). Then this operation is described by a set of Kraus operators $$\{V_k^A\otimes I^B\} $$
such that
$$\sum_k \left(V_k^A\otimes I^B\right)\left(V_k^A\otimes I^B\right)^\dagger =I^A\otimes I^B$$
 Then the state after the operation is

$$\mathcal{E}(\sigma)=\sum_k \left(V_k^A\otimes I^B\right) \sigma \left(V_k^A\otimes I^B\right)^\dagger$$

And the state of Bob's system is

$$ \mathrm{Tr}_A\left(\mathcal{E}(\sigma)\right)=\mathrm{Tr}_A\left(\sum_{k,i} \left(V_k^A\otimes I^B\right) \sigma \left(V_k^A\otimes I^B\right)^\dagger\right)=\mathrm{Tr}_A\left(\sum_{k,i} V_k^A T_i V_k^{A\dagger}\otimes S_i \right)=\sum_i \mathrm{Tr}\left(T_i\right)S_i =\mathrm{Tr}_A(\sigma)$$

Hence there is no effect on Bob's system, and Bob cannot detect wheter Alice has done any operation, and hence extract information from it.

Note that there is no notion of "speed" here, this proof only assumes that the operation Alice does only affect her system (if she's allowed to do operations on Bob's system she clearly can communicate) and that quantum operations are completely positive trace preserving maps, which is a basic fact of quantum theory.

This means that pure entanglement cannot be used to communicate information at *any* speed, not even slower than light: entanglement alone isn't enough to communicate!

Nevertheless, entanglement is not useless, as we have [superdense coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdense_coding), which allows to send two classical bits by sending only one qubit, and using entanglement. This is clearly limited by the speed of light, as it requires physically sending a qubit. Since as a matter of fact superdense coding is optimal, you can't do better than this.

Comment: If entanglement is not enough to communicate, what does it need to allow for communication?

Comment: to communicate you need to physically send a qubit, like you would send a classical bit. Entanglement can improve the communication efficiency via superdense coding, but you still have to send something.